# JWT token system - remember me

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I made an auth system with JWTs based on the following flow:

1. On login the server creates a JWT and stores it in the cookie
2. With any action that requires auth the token is verified
3. Each token is valid for 5 minutes and on an action a newly generated token replaces it

Right now I'm trying to implement a "remember me" feature; I believe I should be creating a refresh token if the user checks the "remember me" box on login which has a much longer expire time (e.g. a month) and allows the client to execute actions without having to login every time.

Is this the proper approach or is there a more convenient and better way? From what the articles I've read say, apparently I'm supposed to make the access token have a short expiration date but have a refresh token with a longer expire time; how does that even help though? If a hacker gains access to the refresh token what's the point? How can this be secure?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a bigger project and worried about security then I would go with an API for tokens such as 0Auth as they have a refresh token rotation and token automatic reuse detection. This will make sure that refresh tokens do not stick around for long and that no one can use an old refresh token to get an access token to your server. It is certainly hard to decide between convenience for the user and security but you can find good middle ground. Refresh tokens are definitely the way to go if you are looking for users to appear to stay logged in without having to have them re-authenticate. Ill drop the article below on Auth0 if you are interested

https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/